# How to compare Json date and return a new array

Tags: javascript

I have problem with the code below. I'm trying to return all votes between two dates, but for some reason it doesn't work well.

FirstShiftStart date -> 2022-12-21 8:0:0

FirstShiftEnd date -> 2022-12-21 14:0:0

```
let current_datetime = new Date();    
var firstShiftStart = current_datetime.getFullYear() + "-" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getDate() + " " + 08 + ":" + 00 + ":" + 00;
var firstShiftEnd = current_datetime.getFullYear() + "-" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getDate() + " " + 14 + ":" + 00 + ":" + 00;;


    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

votesforDay is returning only today's records(all data is ok).

However, the last line it's returning empty array.

```
    var votesforDay = dataAllJson.filter(x => x.Created >= today);

    int likesFirstShift = votesforDay.filter(x => x.Created >= firstShiftStart && x.Created <= firstShiftEnd && x.Choice == "Like").length;
```

```
int likesFirstShift = votesforDay.filter(x => x.Created >= firstShiftStart && x.Created <= firstShiftEnd && x.Choice == "Like").length;
```

```
Choice: "Like"
​​
Created: "2022-12-21 07:50:04"
​​
Id: 12123
```

Comment: What is "_Json date_"?

Comment: Json data, that has property Created(date)

Comment: A serialized date object is a string and looks like this: `"2022-12-21T13:59:01.756Z"` (notice the UTC time), it's not a live object, and can't be parsed back to live object from JSON with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @Teemu, I serialized the object before passing to JS;    var originalVotes = Model.Votes.Select(x => new VoteFullModelJs { Choice = x.Choice, Id = x.Id, Created = x.Created.ToString("yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") });

Comment: Can you post the contents of `dataAllJson`?

Comment: array of objects(Id, Choice, Created) @FiddlingAway

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your code won't return a thing, if these conditions are not met:

- the `Created` property of a specific `JSON` element of your array must be greater than or equal to `firstShiftStart` (`2022-12-21 08:00:00`, in your code)
- the `Created` property of that same `JSON` element of your array must be less than or equal to `firstShiftEnd` (`2022-12-21 14:00:00`, in your code)
- finally, the `Choice` property of that same `JSON` should be equal to `Like`

Since we know only one element of your array of `JSON` objects, we can see that one of the conditions is not met - the timestamp is before `firstShiftStart`, and your filter will remove it from the array.

Also, there are some syntax errors in your code - leading zeroes, double zeroes, etc.

I've taken the liberty of fixing it up a bit (not entirely), and changing your filtering in the last line, so that you may better understand why your code isn't returning anything.

```js
let current_datetime = new Date();

var firstShiftStart = current_datetime.getFullYear() + "-" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getDate() + " 08:00:00";

var firstShiftEnd = current_datetime.getFullYear() + "-" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getDate() + " 14:00:00";

var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

var dataAllJson = [
    {
        "Choice": "Like",
        "Created": "2022-12-22 11:50:04",
        "Id": 1
    },
    {
        "Choice": "dislike",
        "Created": "2022-12-22 11:44:04",
        "Id": 2
    },

    {
        "Choice": "dislike",
        "Created": "2022-12-22 07:50:04",
        "Id": 3
    },
    {
        "Choice": "dislike",
        "Created": "2022-12-22 07:50:04",
        "Id": 4
    },
    {
        "Choice": "dislike",
        "Created": "2022-12-22 07:50:04",
        "Id": 5
    },
    {
        "Choice": "Like",
        "Created": "2022-12-22 07:50:04",
        "Id": 6
    },

];

var votesforDay = dataAllJson.filter(x => x.Created >= today);
var likesFirstShift = votesforDay.filter(function(x) {
  if(x.Created >= firstShiftStart && x.Created <= firstShiftEnd && x.Choice == "Like") {
    console.log(x.Id);
    console.log(x.Created + " >= " + firstShiftStart);
    console.log(x.Created + " <= " + firstShiftEnd);
    console.log(x.Choice + " == Like");
  }
    return x.Created >= firstShiftStart && x.Created <= firstShiftEnd && x.Choice == "Like"
}).length;

console.log("=============================");
console.log(likesFirstShift);
```

Some things to note:

- `firstShiftStart` and `firstShiftEnd` are defined in a slightly different manner. Note the differences between the example and what was in your code
- I've changed the date to todays (22nd of December 2022), so that you can test the code
- I have also filled `dataAllJson` with semi-random data, again, for testing purposes
- `votesForDay.filter(...)` has been expanded to a slightly different notation, for testing purposes (note the `console.log`ging)